# Is query to new added object possible in MS Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, persistence

Is there a way to query or just access newly added object (using ObjectContext.AddObject method) in Entity Framework? I mean situation when it is not yet saved to data store using SaveChanges

I understand that queries are translated to underlying SQL and executed against data store, and it don't have this new object yet. But anyway, I'm curious - if it is not oficially supported, maybe it is possible in theory. If it's not, how developer can deal with it? Manually track new objects and query them using Linq to objects?

The same question also applies to LinqToSql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In EF, if you use this code, you have all the entities that are already loaded in the context (including newly added ones) :

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged).Select(o => o.Entity).OfType<YourObjectType>()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not longer working with EF, but this is hopefully useful.

Answer (score 2):

"The same question also applies to LinqToSql."

For LINQ-to-SQL, look at [`DataContext.GetChangeSet()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx); this has [3 separate collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset_properties.aspx) for the pending `.Inserts`, `.Updates` and `.Deletes`

Note that the `ChangeSet` is a snapshot of when the `GetChangeSet()` method is called; you need to re-query to see any additional changes.