# LINQ to Entities / SQL - Way of seeing what is attached to object context?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Bit of an odd question but is there a way of seeing what objects are attached to my object context. I am getting a few random problems and it would really be helpful to solve them if i could see what's been attached and not yet saved through "SaveChanges".

Answer (Entity Framework) : `context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged).Select(o => o.Entity).OfType<YourObjectType>();`

Comment: A little bit of confusion here, I started my title with simply linq as i expected the answer could have come from EF or SQL. This did not turn out to be the case. However for the benefit of others answers this question for both these framworks can be found here so i have kept the title and tags for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding (or oversimplifying) your question but it sounds like [GetChangeSet()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) could help you?

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion lead to a relativly simple solution. GetChangeSet only works with linq to sql and i am using Entities but i found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326186/is-query-to-new-added-object-possible-in-ms-entity-framework , and it really helped me out with "context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged).Select(o => o.Entity).OfType<YourObjectType>()" which can be used in EF.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/GettingChangedEntitiesFromLINQToSQLDataContext.aspx) might be of interest.

It covers using reflection to look inside (private) fields in the DataContext for changed items. I believe it could be adapted to show all items, not just changed ones.

Comment: Many thanks, i will read it first thing tomorrow morning at work. Sounds like it should help me out.

Comment: That's for LINQ to SQL only. It won't work for EF. (Though I see this question has been tagged LINQ to SQL in the past.)

Answer (score 0):

You look at the object state entries in the ObjectStateManager. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplAudingTrailUsingEFP1.aspx) has an example.